# I don't understand why I'm getting "x is not defined" in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've just started programming in Python and I'm getting *x is not defined* but I have no idea why it is saying that considering I think it is defined.

```
def menu():
    x = 0
    while x != 1 or 2:
        print "menu"
        print "1)login"
        print "2)under dev"
        x = raw_input('select menu option')
        if x == 1 or 2:
            break
menu()
if x=='1':
    print "enter username:"
y = raw_input()
if y=="username":
    print "enter password:"
z = raw_input()
if z=="password":
    print "password accepted"
elif x=='2':
    print "under development"
elif y or z == False:
    print "username or password incorrect"
```

Comment: `elif y or z == False:` not correct, this will check `if y` or `if z == False` you want `if y == False or z == False`

Answer (score 6):

`x` is a *local* variable in the `menu()` function, it doesn't exist outside of `menu()`.

You could return it from `menu()` then store the value in a new `x` in your code:

```
def menu():
    x = None
    while x not in ('1', '2'):
        print "menu"
        print "1)login"
        print "2)under dev"
        x = raw_input('select menu option')
    return x

x = menu()
```

Note that I fixed several problems with your code in `menu()` as well.

- `raw_input()` returns a string, but you test if `x` is integer 1 or 2 instead. I changed the code to test for the strings `'1'` and `'2'` instead.
- Don't use `x != 1 or 2`, that does *not* mean what you think it means. It tests if `x != 1` is True, and if not, it tests if `2` is True. `2` is *always* `True` because all non-zero numbers are considered True in a boolean context.

  I replaced that with a `x not in ('1', '2')` test.
- There is no need to test `x` inside the loop again and execute a `break`; the `while` loop will just exit on its own without that test.
- It doesn't really matter what `x` is set to at the start of `menu()`, as long as it is not `'1'` or `'2'`. `None` is a good choice to signal that it is 'empty'.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `x` is defined in the `menu` function. It is this a local variable, and only accessible from the body of the function. This answer has good explanation of [Python scoping rules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/292502/5353).

Answer (score 0):

If you are still confused about using global and local variables, look at [this website](http://www.python-course.eu/global_vs_local_variables.php).

Answer (score 0):

Your Problem is because of Python's scopes
which are stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/292502/1931274) (and below):
LEGB Rule.

- **L**ocal.
  Names assigned in any way within a function, and not declared global in that function.
- **E**nclosing function locals.
  Name in the local scope of any and all enclosing functions (`def` or `lambda`), form inner to outer.
- **G**lobal (module).
  Names assigned at the top-level of a module file, or declared global in a def within the file.
- **B**uilt-in (Python).
  Names preassigned in the built-in names module : `open, range, SyntaxError`, etc

So, your `x` variable is a variable **local** to `main()`. So, to get the variable out of the **local** scope, you can get the global variable to the local scope too.

Your code seems to have various logical errors (and some `NameError`s). I've tried to understand and have changed/reformed your code, to something that will work.

```
def menu():
    global x
    while x not in ('1','2'): # 1
        print "   Menu"
        print "1) Login"
        print "2) Under dev"
        x = raw_input('Select menu option: ') # 2
        if x in ('1','2'): # 1
            break
x = ''
menu()
# 3
if x == '1':
    y = raw_input("enter username: ") # 2
    z = raw_input("enter password: ") # 2
    if y != 'username' or z != 'password': # 4
        print "username or password incorrect"
    else: # 5
        print 'You will be logged in'
elif x == '2':
    print "Under development"
```

Other than the grammatical changes, lets see the changes on the logical part.(The numbers in comments refer to the point which elaborates on the change.)

1. `raw_input` returns a string. So, it will never be `1` or `2` (integers).
   Also, `x != 1 or 2` will evaluate to `True` as it is equivalent to `(x != 1) or (2)` and `2` always has a `True` value in Python.
2. `raw_input` takes a prompt as an argument, which is displayed before taking the input from
3. Simply put, the structure of your ifs and elifs is not correct.
4. `y or z == False` is evaluated to `(y) or (z = False)` And `z` is never `False` as it is a string.
   So, if `y` is not `''`, then this is evaluated to True, but that is not like something you want (it seems)..
5. The code in `else` is executed if the if (and all the elifs) conditionals are `False`.
   Here we give the under development message.

<sub>More coming</sub>